# Is there a top-level layout container in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular-cdk

Is there a top-level container that applies the styles you get with `mat-toolbar` or `mat-card`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093880/angular-material-2-container) seems to recommend using `mat-card`, but that seems weird to put the main body of an app in a `mat-card` and also it comes along with some other baggage (eg, `border-radius` that would need to be unset). I could make a mixin to emulate the styles I see in the dev tools:

```
@mixin toolbar-like()  {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but this seems unidiomatic, and I'm not sure if the CSS changes at different viewport sizes that I need to account for, so that is hacky. In the end I am only talking about a few lines of CSS, but it seems odd I cannot a standard way within the framework to accomplish this.

## What is the *Material-Way* to contain a body content so that it displays naturally alongside other material elements?

Comment: You can use `material-grid` just like `bootstrap grid` as a parent wrapper and also a `fxLayout` of Angular I am using both of them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, if you want to apply styling to your component itself without wrapping it in a container you can use [:host](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host)

Comment: Ah, thanks but that is not what I'm looking for. It's true you can use `:host` to target the component, but I'm looking for a material component or directive to use as a layout container tag.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular 'div' tags with [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

StackBlitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
    <!-- items to layout horizontally -->
    <div>...</div>
    <mat-card>...</mat-card>
    etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this, but the fact that is (crazily) [still beta](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/releases) makes it unusable.

Comment: Interesting that they keep rolling betas.  I have been using it for a while (even in production) and haven't had any issues.